# Are $nimonics$ (nimber mnemonics) a thing?

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-game-theory, online-resources, surreal-numbers

**Note:** The context of the follwing is [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber).

---

I found the following nimber addition mnemonic on the Wikipedia page for [Fano planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane). Inspired by the [Fano plane mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Fano_plane_mnemonic), I decided to see if I could make a nimber multiplication mnemonic & much to my surprise I was able to figure 1 out!

**Addition mnemonic**

[image: nimber addition mnemonic]

**My 1st multiplication mnemonic**
[image]

**How it works** Find a line (for example from 6-2), the midpoint (11) is the product. The previous example works all along the outer edge (eg. the line from 11-9 has 2 a midpoint). For lines thru the origin, the product is 1 (eg. the line from 7-11 has $\bigstar \equiv* \equiv 1$ as a midpoint).

---

My initial graph was based on the fano plane, but I'm not sure how to create that in [Quiver](https://q.uiver.app/) (*aside* what can I use to create graphs like the addition mnemonic?). While trying to rearrange my diagram I stumbled upon a another configuration:

**Block Nimonic**

This works similar to the previous nimonic, however it **doesn't** go around the corners ‍♀️

[image]

---

I wasn't able to find much online about nimonics, but I was able to produce more of both types & figure out some patterns, which led me to creating this nimonic:

[image: nimber multiplication mnemonic for numbers 1-15]

There's ***a lot*** going on (& there are *still* lines that can be added )..

**TLDR** Different line types emerging from the midpoints *point* $\mapsto$ towards the endpoints (eg. the squiggly lines from the midpoint 2 point at $\mapsto$ the endpoints 5 & 4).

**Aside** In this process of doing all of this I got tired of using the [multiplication table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber#Addition_and_multiplication_tables) on Wikipedia, so I had ChatGPT help me make a [nimber multiplier](https://hypersurreal.github.io/_/*/) (available beneath interactive Quiver chart - works up to 15x15).

**Does something like this already exist?** Or is there some other concept this is possibly related to? I'm a bit perplexed..

---

**Edit** I found 2 numonics (new nimonics) that feel more natural based on the "graph of [$G_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2_(mathematics)) as a subgroup of F4 and E8 projected into the Coxeter plane" (whatever that means..)
[image: Graph of G2 as a subgroup of F4 and E8 projected into the Coxeter plane]
[image: nimber multiplication mneumonic based on G2 graph]

& "The A2 Coxeter plane projection of the 12 vertices of the cuboctahedron" (again no clue..)

[image]
[image: nimber multiplication mneumonic based on G2 graph]

**Aside** I find it interesting that both graphs overlap (w/ a $90^o$ rotation) however the 2nd numonic isn't just a rotation of the first.

These are essentially the same layout as the previous large numonic, just slightly rearranged. I think there is a probably some optimal configuration that I haven't found yet ‍♀️

**Bonus question**: I have been able to get multiple fano planes that embed into the larger nimonic. **How many unique nimonics exist? How many unique smaller nimonics can be embedded into any given larger nimonic?**

**Double bonus**: What does $G_2$ have to do with nimbers &/or combinatorial games?

Comment: You lost me already here : "Find a line (for example from 6-2), the midpoint (11) is the product."

Comment: @Peter ChatGPT only helped write code for the calculator. Sorry my explanation is not more clear. The diagrams should be composed differently (with curved lines as Fano planes are projective spaces), but I'm not sure how to do that currently..

Comment: If you use nonstandard ways for the product , this must be mentioned explicitely.

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what u mean by nonstandard ways for the product? I went off of what I found on Wikipedia.

Comment: Obviously , $6\cdot 2=12$ is not meant which everyone would assume to be the product , if no specific other definition is used.

Comment: @Peter Sorry.. I guess I can make it more clear the context is Nimbers?

Comment: @MarkS. Sorry if I'm using the wrong symbol. I thought 6+2=4 & 6*2 =11.

Comment: The context is clear to me and I understand why $6×2=11$. I suggest you ignore comments from people who are unfamiliar with nimbers and unwilling to look it up.

Comment: @marks. In nimber _addition_ we have $6+2=4$.  Multiplication is different.

Comment: No. The author is allowed to assume basic familiarity with the subject matter. It would be absurd to require every question on this site to rehearse all basic definitions. It is not reasonable for you to expect to understand questions about [tag:surreal-numbers] or [tag:combinatorial-game-theory] if you don't have at least minimal background knowledge in these areas.

Comment: @MJD Thank u. I don't really understand nimbers, but my intuition for them is slowly growing. Would love any insight u may have! 

Comment: "I won't explain the rules this time" Then what are we supposed to do with these diagrams past the "block nimonic"? And how are we supposed to answer your questions about the later graphs? Even if we could guess correctly with some effort, this is not a puzzle site.

Comment: @MarkS. They are in essentially the same layout as the 1 I explained. I can add more explanation if u feel that would help; just felt the question was already getting rather lengthy ‍♀️

Comment: For instance, there's no other number on the arrow from 2 to 11 in the one after the "block nimonic", so it's not obvious what one should do. And there's no explanation of the different types of arrows, either. Similarly, the later diagram introduces new tiny arrows that go unexplained. "just felt the question was already getting rather lengthy" Long and clear is better than short and cryptic. (Also, you have 4 or 5 questions, so this could use more organization/focus for that, too.)

Comment: @MarkS. I tried to use different line types to make different lines more clear. Re: 2 & 11, 2 is the midpoint of the line from 11 to 9. "TLDR Different line types emerging from the midpoints point  towards the endpoints (eg. the squiggly lines from the midpoint 2 point at the endpoints 5 & 4)."

Comment: For anyone interested: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123357/nimber-mnemonics